# Stacked Bar Chart matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'country': ['US', 'DE', 'IT', 'US', 'DE', 'IT', 'US', 'DE', 'IT'],
        'year': [2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002],
        'share': [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.4]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to display the data with a stacked bar chart.

X-axis: year,
Y-axis: share,
Color: country

All the three bars for 2000, 2001 and 2002 should have the same height (for each year, the total of the share == 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with `stacked=True`:

```
data.pivot('year', 'country', 'share').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How to put the legend on the left?

Comment: add `.legend(loc='upper left')`

Comment: I think you need to search a bit by yourself, the doc is quite well written ;) `.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))`

Comment: @mozway When using `bbox_to_anchor=` it is recommended to also use `loc=`. The default is `loc='best'` which can change depending on the data in the plot.

Comment: @PineappleP [How to put the legend outside the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804)